# Where can I ride a pump trolley?

Tags: trains, where-on-earth

Almost three decades ago I had the pleasure to ride a [pump trolley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handcar). I remembered the ease of getting the thing in motion and the speed you can get. Unfortunately I was only allowed to ride for about 100 meters.

Today I watched an episode of [Masha and the bear](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qd6OtRox9V8), where Santa Claus was driving such a pump trolley. Of course this was a cartoon, but it made me wonder if there is still some place in the world where one could rent or drive such a pump trolley for a longer journey.

I know that there are multiple locations where you can cycle on old railway tracks ([example](http://www.grenzland-draisine.eu/)). I am actually looking for the real thing, such as depicted in the picture below.

[image: Example of a pump trolley from Wiki commons] Source: [WikiCommons](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Pump_trolley.jpg)

Bonus points for someone pointing to a pump trolley which can be used for a multiple day hiking trip.

Comment: Welcome back.  You should watch the entire series. :)  Do you care where the ride is?  And it's a real thing just slightly newer model.

Comment: What a great question! Best of its type so far this year (-: I think everyone who has seen one of these in a movie or cartoon has wanted to try it.

Comment: Wow, how did I miss this question 3 months ago? Love it!

Comment: Draisines are equally real.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see you live in Belgium, so here is an alternative closer to home:

- There's [this one](http://draisinentour.de/de/draisinen) in Germany.
  [image]

There's a [list](http://www.draisinenfahrten.de/links.html) of a lot of draisine offers by country, but so far all of the ones I checked out except the above one where the cycling ones. Maybe if you go through them, you can find another one.

Answer (score 15):

You can ride a pump trolley at the [Shelburne Falls Trolley Museum](http://www.sftm.org/), although it doesn't look to be quite the vintage of your example.  [Reviews suggest it is indeed quite enjoyable](http://www.yelp.com/biz/shelburne-falls-trolley-museum-shelburne-falls).

[image]

Another option is in [Goleta](http://www.goletadepot.org/visitor_rides.php) with a handcar that seems more your kind of vintage (albeit a replica created in the 1980s).

[image]

[Carson City](http://renotahoe.about.com/od/historicsites/ss/Tour-The-Nevada-State-Railroad-Museum-In-Carson-City_4.htm) also gives you a chance to do so.

[image]

There's also [a general entry race at Folsom](http://www.fedshra.org/handcar.html), which seems like it provides the handcar for you.

Answer (score 7):

In the US there is also rides available in [Steamtown USA](http://www.nps.gov/stea/planyourvisit/tour01.htm) in Scranton, PA

[image]

If you really feel like it you can try the [Folsom HandCar Derby](http://psvrr.org/handcar.html) in Folsom, CA.  Not as old hand car as you have listed by still could be fun. :)

[image]